# Query with a JSON data in the Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a query that gathers data based on a JSON field

```
SELECT `a`.`id`,`package_cost`,`package_duration`,`b`.`id`  `product_page`, `description`, `product_lifecycle`
FROM `j20_package` AS `a` 
INNER JOIN `j20_product` AS `b` ON (`a`.`package_product_name` = `b`.`id`) 
WHERE `a`.`published` = '1'
```

where a is

```
 id   package_cost    package_duration    package_product_name
 1     29             365                 {"0":"11","1":"12"}
 2     40             365                 {"0":"10","1":"8"}
 3     30             365                 {"0":"1","1":"10"}
 4     45             365                 {"0":"4","1":"10"}
```

and b is

```
 id   product_cost    product_lifecycle   
 10   500             Mark
 8    800             John
```

so it's simple enough to pull the package name into an array

```
$packagesonly = json_decode($packages_id, true);
```

I tried this and then using IN as part of the inner join but it failed.

It's not really possible to create a separate Join table so I need to try to make it work in this query or a number of queries and code.

Comment: How do you decide whether or not to qualify a column?

Comment: If your `package_product_name` contains multiple entities ID's and is not literal name of product, then you have wrong structure of database. Then you need to use `a.package_product_name LIKE ...`

Comment: Also what version of MySql? MySql  5.7 has JSON support https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: I know the database structure sucks! But it is what it is and I have to live with it.  If I redesigned it then I'd have a join table which would make things easier.  I think the answer is code round about it rather than using Mysql to solve the problem